# Missing table lines

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I tried using \multicolumn but the vertical lines of the table disappeared.

Here's my code:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{||l | l  l ||}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Parámetro} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Eje} \\ 
                            & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Paradigmático} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Sintagmático} \\
          \hline
    Peso  & integridad & ámbito estructural \\
    \hline
    Cohesión & paradigmaticidad & Cohesión \\
    \hline
    Variabilidad & variabilidad paradigmática & Variabilidad sintagmática \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

[image: table missing vertical lines]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want LaTeX to draw a vertical line at the left-hand or right-hand edge of a `\multicolumn` construct, you need to let LaTeX know about your intentions.

E.g., if you want a single vertical line at the right-hand edge, I suggest you replace

```
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{...}
```

and

```
 \multicolumn{1}{l}{...}
```

with either

```
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{...}
```

and

```
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{...}
```

respectively. In case you want a *double* vertical line, use

```
\multicolumn{2}{c||}{...}
```

and

```
\multicolumn{1}{l||}{...}
```

respectively. Can you spot the difference?

---

*Addendum* Here's a complete compilable test document. The first table uses `\multicolumn{2}{c||}{...}` for the text that spans columns 2 and 3. The second table streamlines the table's appearance by getting rid of all vertical lines and using fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{array,multirow,booktabs}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{Variabilidad paradigmática}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less cramped ``look''
  
  \caption{Add caption} \label{tab:addlabel}
    \begin{tabular}{|| l | ll ||}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Parámetro} & \multicolumn{2}{c||}{Eje} \\ 
    \cline{2-3} % <-- new
    & Paradigmático & Sintagmático \\
    \hline
    Peso  & Integridad & ámbito estructural \\
    \hline
    Cohesión & paradigmaticidad & cohesión \\
    \hline
    Variabilidad & variabilidad paradigmática & variabilidad sintagmática \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}    

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
    \caption{Add caption} \label{tab:addlabel2}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} lll @{}}
    \toprule
    Parámetro & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Eje} \\ 
    \cmidrule(l){2-3}
    & Paradigmático & Sintagmático \\
    \midrule
    Peso  & Integridad & ámbito estructural \\
    Cohesión & paradigmaticidad & cohesión \\
    Variabilidad & variabilidad paradigmática & variabilidad sintagmática \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `tabularray` package handle vertical lines in multi column cells differently than "classic" table. These cells doesn't interfere with prescribed vertical lines. So, using it, you have one care less at writing of tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={|| l | ll ||},
                 row{1}={c},
                 hlines
                 }
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    Parámetro
                &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Eje 
                                    &                           \\
                &   Paradigmático   &   Sintagmático            \\
Peso            & integridad        & ámbito estructural        \\
Cohesión        & paradigmaticidad  & Cohesión                  \\
Variabilidad    & variabilidad paradigmática 
                                    & Variabilidad sintagmática \\
    \end{tblr}
  \label{tab:addlabel}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]